# Excel VBA: "Application defined or object defined error" when referencing a worksheet in function

Tags: excel, vba, function, formula, cells

### The Problem:

I have a function which creates a worksheet and populates cells with values and formulas. In this function `createTS` (create test sheet, get it?...), I call sub functions to populate certain sections in of the worksheet. My issues is that I get this error:

```
"application defined or object defined error"
```

whenever I try to call the sub function which takes in `createTS` as one of the parameters since it adds values and formulas to the worksheet that `createTS` is creating (or really is since the output of `createTS` is a worksheet).

I specifically get the error with this line:

```
createTS.Cells(r_aS, c_aS).Value = "Animal #" & aNum & ":"
```

### The Code:

**1) the function createTS:**

*There is a lot of code in this function, much of which I have omitted. Please focus on the parts relevant to the question and assume that other variables not used are irrelevant for now*:

```
Function createTS(ByRef index As Integer, ByRef wBStruct As wBStruct, ByRef gcBStruct As gcBStruct) As Worksheet
    '1) set up worksheet

     '...code...

    '2) variables
    'structure, it is created earlier 
    Dim aL As aL

    With aL
        ReDim .r_aS(gcBStruct.animalNum - 1) 'this is a string array 
        ReDim .c_aS(gcBStruct.animalNum - 1) 'this is a string array
    End With

    'row/col starts
    Dim r_hdStart As Integer          'heading row start
    Dim r_bckCS As Integer            'background counts row start
    Dim r_stdCS As Integer            'standard counts row start
    Dim r_tStart As Integer           'test section row start
    Dim r_summS As Integer            'summary section row start
    Dim r_aS As Integer               'row of animal section start

    Dim c_hdStart As Integer          'heading column start
    Dim c_aS As Integer               'column of animal section start

    'block sizes (blocks are gaps in between cells of text and defined by row #)
    Dim hspR As Integer             'heading block size
    Dim bsBlock As Integer          'background-standard block size
    Dim stBlock As Integer          'standard-tests block size
    Dim aBlock As Integer           'animal block size
    Dim asBlock As Integer          'animal-summary block size
    Dim sumBlock As Integer         'summary block size

    hspR = 1
    bsBlock = 4
    stBlock = 4
    aBlock = 3
    asBlock = 6
    sumBlock = 4

    'other
    Dim bsNum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim oNum As Integer

    Dim avgBck As String
    Dim soiDate As String
    Dim tcInj As String

    Dim scTempC1 As String
    Dim scTempC2 As String

    'set variables
    oNum = UBound(wBStruct.wTypeBlock(index).animalBlock(0).organName) + 1
    r_hdStart = 1
    c_hdStart = 1

    r_bckCS = r_hdStart + hspR + 1
    bsNum = 2
    r_stdCS = r_bckCS + bsNum + bsBlock + 1
    r_tStart = r_stdCS + bsNum + stBlock + 1
    r_aS = r_tStart + 1
    c_aS = c_hdStart

    '3) Make Headings
    '**********This is how I would like to set cell values and formulas in the sub function************
    'set SoiDate + LAble
    With createTS            
        .Cells(r_hdStart, c_hdStart).Value = "Start of Injection:"
        .Cells(r_hdStart, (c_hdStart + 1)).Value = gcBStruct.soiDate
        soiDate = .Cells(r_hdStart, (c_hdStart + 1)).Address(True, True)        'set soiDate cell
    End With
    'set Background Counts
    '...code...
    'set Standard Counts
   '...code...

'4) create test type section

    '4.1) create test type heading
    '...more code...

    '4.2) create all animal sections '**********I Call the sub function here************

    For j = 0 To (gcBStruct.animalNum - 1)
        aLTemp = createABlock(createTS, j, index, wBStruct, gcBStruct, soiDate, avgBck, tcInj, r_aS, c_aS, oNum)
        r_aS = r_aS + oNum + aBlock + 1
    Next j

End Function
```

*^I understand that a lot of code is omitted, and this might be impossible to test without having values for above variables. I kept most of the variables set in the function for testing purposes (but, as you noted I did not include the variables which are the parameters for `createTS` as they hail from all over the module which this function is in). I can and will add example values for each of the parameters if necessary. My error might be apparent through provided the information I am giving.*

**2) the sub function:**

```
Private Function createABlock(ByRef createTS As Worksheet, ByVal index As Integer, ByVal indexOld As Integer, _
ByRef wBStruct As wBStruct, ByRef gcBStruct As gcBStruct, ByVal soiDate As String, ByVal avgBck As String, _
ByVal tcInj As String, ByVal r_aS As String, ByVal c_aS As String, ByVal oNum As Integer) As aL

'1) Variables
    ' initialize structure and structure's variables
    '...code...

    ' create variables
    Dim aNum As Integer
    '...code...

    ' set variables
    aNum = index + 1
    '...code...

 '************Error occurs below:************** 
    createTS.Cells(r_aS, c_aS).Value = "Animal #" & aNum & ":"

'...lots and lots of code...

End Function
```

Let me know if you need more information for this problem, but I'm sure it's apparent, and I'm just missing it. Thanks!

Comment: Why are **createTS()** and **createABlock()** *functions* rather than *subs?*  Functions are normally used to return single values to worksheet cells.

Comment: `createTS` is a function because in a driver sub, I populate an array of worksheets with the worksheets created by `createTS`. The latter is a function because it returns a structure containing the positions of certain cells for reference later in the function.

Comment: Given the scope of the sub function it is most likely not related but you have a function called `createTS` and then a parameter in a sub function called `createTS`. You should change this as if nothing else it is misleading. Not sure but it might think that you are trying to access a propery of a function as supposed the function `createTS` as supposed to the parameter defined by `ByRef createTS As Worksheet`

Comment: Also not related i see you do the same thing here `Dim aL As aL`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you did not post that part of the code, you never assign a value to the function name within the function procedure. And since this is an object, you'll need to use the Set keyword

e.g:

```
Set CreateTS = ActiveSheet
```